# Why does Spring's <jdbc:embedded-database> throw a SQLSyntaxErrorException?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-jdbc

I'm learning Spring and now I'm trying out Spring's **<jdbc:embedded-database>** tag in the spring-jdbc namespace. I always run into the same error: a "**java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found**" when my test data is supposed to be inserted.

It seems the schema wasn't created or the privileges aren't correctly processed. When I use the debugger it seems the schema creation script is correctly executed. The username and password also seem correctly set when the default database is initialized.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tests</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
          <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.9</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

src/test/resources/**spring-context.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

</beans>
```

src/test/resources/**schema.sql**

```sql
create table if not exists tuser (
    userId varchar(255) not null,
    admin bit not null,
    primary key (userId)
);
```

src/test/resources/**data.sql**

```sql
insert into tuser
(userid, admin) 
values ("testUser0", 0);
```

src/test/java/test/**TestCase.java**

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-context.xml")
public class TestCase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }

}
```

**Console output**

```
[nick@localhost ~/dev/workspaces/juno/spring-tests]$ mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spring-tests 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ spring-tests ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/nick/dev/workspaces/juno/spring-tests/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ spring-tests ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ spring-tests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ spring-tests ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ spring-tests ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/nick/dev/workspaces/juno/spring-tests/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ spring-tests ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/nick/dev/workspaces/juno/spring-tests/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.TestCase
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:05 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-context.xml]
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1a2a46d1: startup date [Wed Jun 12 10:59:06 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:06 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons                                       
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@45709319: defining beans [dataSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy                                                             
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:06 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory initDatabase
INFO: Creating embedded database 'dataSource'
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:07 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:07 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
INFO: Done executing SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql] in 7 ms.
Jun 12, 2013 10:59:07 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [data.sql]
2013-06-12T10:59:07.496+0200  SEVERE  Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3afe79c] to prepare test instance [test.TestCase@118eb4a8]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [data.sql]: insert into tuser (userid, admin) values ("testUser0", 0)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [data.sql]: insert into tuser (userid, admin) values ("testUser0", 0)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:56)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.initDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:136)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [data.sql]: insert into tuser (userid, admin) values ("testUser0", 0)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:201)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:134)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CompositeDatabasePopulator.populate(CompositeDatabasePopulator.java:55)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:47)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: testUser0
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:186)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: testUser0
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
        ... 56 more

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.364 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  test(test.TestCase): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.828s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 12 10:59:07 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project spring-tests: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/nick/dev/workspaces/juno/spring-tests/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Any luck getting this to go?

Comment: Yes, thanks. See comment on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **data.sql** file there is an error:

```
insert into tuser
(userid, admin) 
values ("testUser0", 0);
```

should be (Sql uses single quotes):

```
insert into tuser
(userid, admin) 
values ('testUser0', 0);
```

This may be the source of the `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found` error.  I get burnt by this one all the time, I really wish SQL and Java's string literals used the same terminators.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Really useless error message. I tested my SQL statement in Eclipse and it ran without problems.  Thanks for the speedy solution.